# How to Search All the Files in a Folder with JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have a program that (so far) searches through a file for certain keywords and prints all the lines that have that keyword in it. The problem is it can only search one text file at a time. How can I make it so it searches every text file inside of a folder?

This is the code for the Find File Button that opens just a text file

```
        findFileButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JFileChooser fileChoice = new JFileChooser();
            fileChoice.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

            int returnVal = fileChoice.showOpenDialog(AdminPanel.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                File file = fileChoice.getSelectedFile();
                wantedFile = file.getAbsolutePath();

            }
        }
    });
```

I tried switching the fileSelectionMode to FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES but when i clicked on a folder it would trigger my try/catch for a file wasn't found/specified.

Any help? 
Thanks,
~Zmyth

Comment: You already know how to use JFileChooser to select a directory, so that part is irrelevant. And you know how to read a single file. Am I right in thinking that what you're really asking is just "How can I find all the files in a directory?"?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, when using `FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES`, you will either get a file OR directory.  You need to check the type using `File.isDirectory` to determine what you should do.  If it's a directory, then you need to list all the files within it and process them as required, if it's a file, you just need to process it as normal.

If you only want the user to be able to select directories, you could use `DIRECTORIES_ONLY`

To search the directory...

## You could...

Use one of the [`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) methods to list all the files from within the selected directory.

This will only list the files for the current directory, if you want to do a recursive search, you need to implement this yourself, but's not to hard

## You could...

Use [`Files#walkFileTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) which can be used to walk the current directory and sub directories, depending how you code the `FileVisitor`

See [Walking the File Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I was unclear in my original question, I wasn't sure how to go about searching for the files in a folder instead of just a file. I was able to get it eventually though with the help of the one answer. I would up vote it but I don't have enough reputation yet. This is what I was looking for:

```
findFileButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JFileChooser fileChoice = new JFileChooser();
            fileChoice.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

            int returnVal = fileChoice.showOpenDialog(Panel.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                File folder = fileChoice.getCurrentDirectory();
                File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
                {
                    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
                    {
                        wantedFilesList.add(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
                        currentFilesList.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                    }
                    else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
                    {
                        // Blerg
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });
```